# Alias to make emacs open a file in a new buffer (NOT frame) and be activated/come to front?

Tags: macos, emacs, applescript, dot-emacs, emacsclient

What I have so far is

```
alias em="open -a /Applications/Emacs.app "$@" && osascript -e 'tell application "Emacs.app" to activate'"
```

But I am stumped.

**With that code, em file.txt will activate, but won't open the file**. And I get '22:23: syntax error: Expected end of line but found unknown token. (-2741)'

---

Doing

```
alias em=open -a /Applications/Emacs.app "$@"
```

Works fine and then it will open the file, but obviously not bring emacs to the front.

---

And for some strange reason

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Emacs.app" to activate'
```

doesn't activate emacs.... I have no idea what is going on.

---

I am happy to fix this either with alias code, or with .emacs code

---

edit: see comments for another thing tried.

Comment: It looks like you really want to use `emacsclient` in combination with an emacs server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the problem be that you need to escape you quotes, like this?

```
alias em="open -a /Applications/Emacs.app \"$@\" && osascript -e 'tell application \"Emacs.app\" to activate'"
```

Comment: Thanks, got rid of the error, but now it tries to load the directory of the file rather than the file, and doesn't activate the Emacs window. Strange. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

Works fine for me.

Found it [here](https://github.com/topfunky/PeepOpen-Issues/issues/13)

Answer (score 2):

I have the following in my `.bashrc` sourced by my `.profile`:

```
alias emacs='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app "$@"'
```

And in my `.emacs` custom area:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; yadda yadda
 ;;...
 '(ns-pop-up-frames nil))
```

Or if you don't like to `M-x customize-variable` your way into it, as Jeff said:

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

I didn't need any AppleScript to do this; although I noticed you were missing the `end tell`? Anyway, works like a charm for me, pops Emacs open, or uses the existing window if there is one, and it's on top, and the Terminal remains ready for more input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
emacsclient -nt somefile
```

in your terminal, which would open specified file(s) in new buffer using your existing frame rather than a new client frame.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html