# how to make emacs open all buffers in one window (debian/linux/gnome)

Tags: linux, emacs, debian

In osx I make all new emacs buffers open in the same window/frame by putting this in .emacs.

(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)

[Alias to make emacs open a file in a new buffer (NOT frame) and be activated/come to front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068819/alias-to-make-emacs-open-a-file-in-a-new-buffer-not-frame-and-be-activated-com)

I want to be able to do the same in debian (gnome). Is it possible? A solution that will also work for xmonad (and similar wms) would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop-up-frames` is a standard emacs variable:

```
pop-up-frames is a variable defined in `window.el'.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
Whether `display-buffer' should make a separate frame.
If nil, never make a separate frame.
If the value is `graphic-only', make a separate frame
on graphic displays only.
Any other non-nil value means always make a separate frame.

You can customize this variable.
```

Use `customize` or put this

```
(custom-set-variables '(pop-up-frames nil))
```

into your `.emacs`.

This, of course, only affects Emacs displaying buffers.
If you start a new Emacs, the new process will create a new window.
To achieve what you, apparently, want, you will need to [run Emacs as a daemon](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon) and open files using `emacsclient`.

Comment: for some reason, this does not work for me, have you tested it?

Comment: I put the line of text in my .emacs (did save it) and the change seems to have been registered as far as I could see in the customize menu (I'm unfamiliar with it). I restarted emacs and the computer. Still, when I open txtFile1 and txtFile2 they appear in separate windows.

Comment: you need to run `emacs` as a daemon and open files using `emacsclient`, see an edit