# How to open multiple files in a single window in emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, emacs24, nautilus

Using Debian, when selecting multiple files in nautilus and opening them in emacs 23 all of these start in the same window with a different buffer for each.

However with emacs-snapshot (GNU Emacs 24.4.50.1) all of these files gets opened in different frames, which I find very annoying as I usually like to have all of these files grouped together.

How can I have the old behavior of selecting files in nautilus and having them open in a  single frame with multiple buffers?

I know I can drag and drop, or opening from a terminal, but I would prefer to select from nautilus.

Comment: Are you using the term window to mean what Emacs users call a window, or are you using the term window and meaning to say what Emacs users call a frame instead?

Comment: The following link to a related thread may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15278820/2112489   *`pop-up-frames` is a variable defined in `window.el`.  Whether `display-buffer` should make a separate frame.  If `nil`, never make a separate frame.  If the value is `graphic-only`, make a separate frame on graphic displays only.  Any other non-nil value means always make a separate frame.  You can customize this variable.*

Comment: Is nautilus starting multiple independent instances of Emacs (one per file)? Or creating multiple frames for a single instance? (If you type `C-x C-b` do you see all the files listed, or just one?)

Comment: I'm using window for what in emacs is a frame @lawlist, I'll edit the question. It starts multiple independent instances, `C-x C-b` only shows one file.

Comment: I tried the answer to the related question but it doesn't work. I started the daemon and try running with the emacsclient but I get the same behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458800/how-to-use-one-instance-of-emacs-as-the-default-text-editor-linux